# List release configuration options with dotnet cli

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnet-cli

When working with the [`dotnet` cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet), several commands like build, take in an option to pass the release configuration

> `-c|--configuration <CONFIGURATION>`
> Defines the build configuration. The default for most projects is Debug, but you can override the build configuration settings in your project.

You can see the possible options in Visual Studio:

[image: Configuration Manager]

Is there any way to list all to possible release configuration options via CLI?